# Delete 'server' tag

Tags: support, tags, server

I don't think the 'server' tag serves any purpose at all on a site that's all about servers.  Might as well have a 'Programming' tag on StackOverflow.

---

Perhaps it would be better to have tags linux-server, windows-server, linux-client, windows-client and so on.  A question about problems with windows clients connecting to a linux samba server could then be given the appropriate tags, and the part with -server would actually be useful.

Comment: On a daily basis I also deal with users, software, networks, security, workstations, *etc*.  I've seen questions, on SF, directly related to each of these items.  None of these items *are* servers, nor would they qualify for a [server] tag.  But this is a community-built site.  You brought your question to the correct place to be addressed.

Comment: +1, I **HATE** that tag. It does seem kind of redundant in 99% of cases.

Comment: While I agree that we don't require the server tag, this site is NOT "all about servers". Your view of system administrations is too narrow. A significant number of questions are unrelated to servers. Likewise, there are many admins who never get to work on a server at all.

Comment: The 'server' tag does help to distinguish a question from 'storage' (Like a Netapp or storage array, not a server), or 'networking' (also not a server) or 'security policies'.

Comment: @Stefan, while I see your point I think the server tag is far too generic to be of any real value. Server questions should be tagged with one or more tags appropriate to the actual make and model of server to be useful.

Answer (score 4):

We already have several specific server tags like server-hardware and email-server.  So I think it's a good idea to get rid of the server tag and have tags like linux-server and windows-server instead.

Comment: I agree. "Server" is far too generic, it doesn't help when searching and doesn't help to categorize or organize the questions.

Comment: +1 for too generic, that is a better reason for deleting the tag rather than the OP's idea. Not all questions on here are [server] related, as pointed out by jscott above.